# What functions can I use in Open CV to close the border of a rectangle in an image?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am working on a project to detect license plates.

The problem is some license plates are damaged, and as shown below have missing corners. This means that when I try to find contours it doesn't detect the license plate as it's not a complete shape.

[image]

I have tried using erosion / dilation and the result isn't very good, it also still doesn't connect the lines to close the gap of the rectangle.
`cv::dilate(image, image, cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1, -1), 0);` and `cv::erosion(image, image, cv::Mat(),cv::Point(-1, -1), 0);`

[image]

What set of functions can I use to complete the license plate boarder so it will be detected as a single contour?

Comment: i recommend you to use OCR module of OpenCV for detecting text,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got no idea why you'd want the border, but I'll ignore that part for a second.

Your problem is that you're trying to use pixel operations. However, pixel operations are local, and you need a larger-scale operation here: line detection. The Hough transform would work nicely. You can then pick out two pairs of lines which form the horizontal and vertical edges (projection means they're likely not orthogonal, but they're probably close to orthogonal.)

These lines will cross at the exact corners of the rectangle, not the rounded corners, but that's a minor problem.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, intention behind detecting license would be to get a image which shows the alphanumeric characters in it. So following method can be tried:

If you can detect all the alphanumeric characters in the original image then the bounding box of all the characters would serve as a license plate. This will be correct if you keep a criteria depending upon what character and how many characters are present in a valid license plate. Since valid set of characters would always be present strictly in a particular manner w.r.t space between them, bounding box will be easy to calculate.